# Hover effect on IconButton in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[IconButton Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsYHX.png)

This is an iconButton from Material-UI that I am using. As you can see there is a slight grey border around the icon when you hover on it. What is the property to disable this? I have not found it in Material-UI docs, and I need to get rid of this grey hover feature.

Code:

```
<IconButton>
    <BackButton />
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 14):

(Alternative Way)

You can also override the IconButton style via MuiThemeProvider:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiIconButton: {
      root: {
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: "$labelcolor"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And Wrap your component that you want to edit with this code:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>

// Your Component here

</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no property to disable it. You'll just have to override the CSS:

```
<IconButton className={"MyCustomButton"}>
    <BackButton />
</IconButton>
```

With a css rule like:

```
.MyCustomButton:hover {
  background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: You can omit the '!important' by using the `classes={{ root: 'MyCustomButton' }}` syntax

Answer (score 5):

```
<IconButton sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "green" } }}>
    <BackButton />
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `makeStyles(styles)` [hook](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#returns-3) logic to change default material-ui IconButton CSS Pseudo-classes e.g. `:hover` [style](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/)

[code example](https://30lp8.csb.app/):

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import ArrowBackIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  myClassName: {
    backgroundColor: "#EFD26E",
    position: "relative",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IconButton color="inherit" className={classes.myClassName}>
        <ArrowBackIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

screens:

- [bg color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOfmd.png)
- [bg color on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzUhq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hoverColor: Colors.transparent` :

```
IconButton(
  hoverColor: Colors.transparent, 
  icon: Icon(Icons.clear_rounded),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Answer (score -3):

You can add hover by wrapping component using @material-ui Tooltip

```
<Tooltip>
  ...your code here
</Tooltip>
```