# How to apply hover effect on Material Icon?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-icons

I am using CSS modules for my project, but Material Icon is not making the changes specified via className prop

```
import SettingsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Settings";
import css from "./LandingPage.module.css";

<SettingsIcon className = {css.settingsButton}/>
```

LandingPage.module.css file

```
.settingsButton{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20;
    top: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    color: white;
}
.settingsButton:hover{
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992947/hover-effect-on-iconbutton-in-material-ui

Comment: @AtifKhan it is for Material Icon Button, I want to apply to hover to a Material Icon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the default `transition` property of `.MuiSvgIcon-root` is more specified than yours.

You need to increase the priority of your css in your `module.css` file using `:global` notation like this:

```css
:global(.App) .settingsButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20;
  top: 20;
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}
:global(.App) .settingsButton:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Note that, in this case `.App` exists my app, if it does not exist in your app, you can wrap your icon with another custom `div` with a specific className and use it instead of `.App`.

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-icon-hover-effect?file=src%2FLandingPage.module.css) for a live working example of this solution.